# How to make a alert after clicking more than one time

Tags: javascript, php, button

Hello my lovely stackies,

After alot of research and no working solution I thought I would try my luck here.
I have a button which POST a formular of a user to the my server.
But my huge problem is, when the user clicks the button how much he wants, I get the formular as often as he clicked on it.

My button and send function is:

```
echo "<form name=\"myForm\" method=\"POST\" action=\"aktenerfassung.php?id=$id&mandnr=$mandnr&countBeleg=$countBeleg\"> \n";
echo "<p align=\"center\"><input id=\"absenden\" align=\"center\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Fehler korrigieren\" name=\"B1\"></p> \n";
echo "</form> \n";
unset($clsAktenerfassung);
```

My solution would be:

```
$(function() {

    $('absenden').on('click', function(e) {
        var trigger = $(this),
        clickCount = trigger.data('clickCount');

        clickCount++;

        trigger.data('clickCount', clickCount);
    }
        if(clickCount > 1) {
            alert('schon einmal klicken')
        }

    });
```

But I can still press the button how much I want and still don't get a alert.
I dont even get a error message from PHP.

This should be the alert:

```
    if(clickCount > 1) {
        alert('schon einmal klicken')
    }
```

If anything is unclear or you need other information or this post already exists in stackoverflow, please tell me.

Thank you already!!

Comment: The question wasn't 100% clear to me but I think using Ajax would help.
When the user presses the button, you send data using Ajax, disable button, and after receiving the response you enable button again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, and instead of catching "more than 1 click", I decided to disable the button and change its text with something like `"Sending datas..."`. I used this simple code to achieve that, with jQuery :

```
$('form[name=myForm]').submit(function()
{
    $('#absenden').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#absenden').html("Sending datas...");
});
```

The event is fired on the form submission, instead of the submit button, because a user can submit with enter or return key.

Comment: Hello Cid, thanks for your help, I tried it and the button didn't disable. Am I making something wrong ? Here is the full button Code: https://pastebin.com/mfx8pVE3 thanks :)

Comment: Did you included jQuery? your code is a mix of php echoing some html and js, it's a pain to read, would you rather ignore the php part and show only the html output?

Comment: Okey it was my mistake. It works now with your solution. Thank you very much!!